# Switching views when pressing button

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to load a new view when I click a button in the app.
The error I am getting is -

```
View Switcher[6867:207] -[UIView pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6010660
```

and the source code snippet is -

```
-(IBAction) blueButtonPressed:(id)sender{

if(self.yellowViewController == nil){
    YellowViewController *yellowController = [[YellowViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YellowView" bundle:nil];
    self.yellowViewController = yellowController;
    //[yellowController release];

    //[self.view addSubview:yellowController.view];
//[self.view pushViewController:self.yellowViewController];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.yellowViewController];
[yellowController release];
}
//[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.yellowViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Here is the header file I am using -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class BlueViewController;
@class YellowViewController;


@interface BlueViewController : UIViewController {  
YellowViewController *yellowViewController;
BlueViewController *blueViewController; 
}
-(IBAction)blueButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@property(retain) YellowViewController *yellowViewController;
@property(retain, nonatomic) BlueViewController *blueViewController;
@end
```

The link to the xcode project is - https://rapidshare.com/files/2403429896/View_Switcher.zip

Comment: What happen if you just uncomment the method call outside of your if statement?

Comment: And your property yellowViewController is set to (retain) ?

Comment: The end result is the same (nothing happens in the simulator), but I did get a new warning - 
incompatible Objective-C types 'struct YellowViewController *', expected 'struct UIViewController *' when passing argument 1 of 'pushViewController:animated:' from distinct Objective-C type

Comment: yellowViewController is set to (retain, nonatomic), but (retain) doesn't make any difference either

Comment: @property(retain) YellowViewController *yellowViewController;

Comment: yellowViewController is a subclass of UIViewController? and you have imported it?

Comment: yes, it is a subclass of UIViewController

Comment: yes, I have this in the header file - YellowViewController *yellowViewController;

Comment: I have also included the header file I am using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pushViewController is a UINavigationController method.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.yellowViewController animated:YES];
```

I'm assuming you are in a UIViewController subclass

---

Could you post an Xcode project I need to see this.

---

Ok, I've look into your code, the problem is that you don't have any navigationController. Your app is structured like a view base application not like a navigation base application.
The result is that your self.navigationController == nil, that is why that call is ignored.

In your application delegate you need some code looking like this

```
UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:switchViewController];
navCon.navigationBarHidden = YES;
self.window.rootViewController = navCon;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

In the applicationFinised...

---

In your code, when you click on your switch in the toolbar, it's "working" because your using this code :

```
[blueViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.view insertSubview:yellowViewController.view atIndex:0];
```

And there is no navigationController in that process.

Comment: yes, i am in UIViewController subclass, but when i use self.navigation controller, i cannot move onto the next view.

Comment: strange, do you get an error or something when you use the self.navigationController?

Comment: there is a warning though  - 
    'UINavigationController' may not respond to '-pushViewController:'

Comment: ... can you post the version of the code that give you that warning. that warning look like you have only 1 parameter instead of the 2 that pushViewController:animated: as.

Comment: i just edited the source code snippet in the question. i get the warning at the line - [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.yellowViewController];

Comment: The link to the xcode project is - https://rapidshare.com/files/2403429896/View_Switcher.zip

Comment: I added that line of code in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method, but that didn't make any difference. 

But I added an else condition after if(self.yellowViewController == nil) and displayed an alert out there. The alert shows properly so that would mean yellowViewController is not nil

Comment: it's not self.yellowViewController that is nil it's the self.navigationController.

Comment: I rewrote the source code using navigation controllers and it works. This is quite a helpful tutorial - http://humblecoder.blogspot.com/2009/04/iphone-tutorial-navigation-controller.html

Answer (score 1):

UIView does not have **pushViewController:animated:** as a method.

You can push only in UINavigationController

Comment: Because the whole pushViewController method is used in a navigationcontroller

Answer (score 1):

You should use `[self.view addSubview:yellowController.view];`

Best to have a navigation controller where you push and pop controllers to or from.